# How to resolve infinite recursion when using metaclasses with python __repr__ function

Tags: python, metaclass

I am trying to implement a logger functionality using metaclasses. This is for learning purposes and may not be a good use case practically.

```
from functools import wraps

def custom_logger(fn):
  @wraps(fn)
  def inner(*args,**kwargs):
    result=fn(*args,**kwargs)
    print(f'LOG: {fn.__qualname__} {args},{kwargs}, result={result}')
    return result
  return inner

class custom_meta(type):
  def __new__(mcls,name,bases,namespace):
    new_obj=super().__new__(mcls,name,bases,namespace)
    for n,o in vars(new_obj).items():
      if callable(o):
        decorated_=custom_logger(o)
        setattr(new_obj,n,decorated_)
    return new_obj

class Person(metaclass=custom_meta):
  def __init__(self,name,age):
    self.name=name
    self.age=age
    
  def say_hello(self):
    print('hello')

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'hi'
    
p=Person('naxi',29);
p.say_hello()
print(p)
```

All of the methods inside Person class are getting decorated perfectly. The only issue I am having is with `__repr__` method which is throwing below error.

```
  File "main.py", line 9, in inner
    print(f'LOG: {fn.__qualname__} {args},{kwargs}, result={result}')
  [Previous line repeated 247 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Also, implementing the `__str__` works just fine.
Can someone please let know why is `__repr__` behaving this way ?

Comment: Tip: The first argument of each method call is the object itself. When formatting position argument tuple `args`, the `__repr__` method is called for each argument.

Comment: Just skip `__repr__` when decorating all methods.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator will change the behavior of *methods* hence a reference of the instance/class should be passed as well.

```
def custom_logger(fn):
  @wraps(fn)
  def inner(self, *args,**kwargs):
    result=fn(self, *args,**kwargs)
    print(f'LOG: {fn.__qualname__} {args},{kwargs}, result={result}')
    return result
  return inner
```

Answer (score 0):

The first of `args` to ordinary instance methods will be `self`. When you simply print `args` at once, it will try to print `self`, which will call `__repr__` on the class -- which will itself try to print `self`, as it is also set-up for logging.

So, you actually coded the infinite recursion in.

A quick fix is to separate the first parameter to the methods, knowing it is probably a reference to the instance, and do not try to print that - or, may, better yet, just skip logging for the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods.

That said, since Python 3.6, for this kind of class transformation, the base-class special `__init_subclass__` method is preferable to metaclasses, as it will avoid a metaclass conflict down the road.

```
class custom_meta(type):
  def __new__(mcls,name,bases,namespace):
    new_obj=super().__new__(mcls,name,bases,namespace)
    for n,o in vars(new_obj).items():
      if callable(o) and n not in ('__str__', '__repr__'):
        decorated_=custom_logger(o)
        setattr(new_obj,n,decorated_)
    return new_obj
```